# Collision among products of binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $k, \ell \geq 2$ be positive integers. Do there exist infinitely many positive integers $N$ such that the equation

$$\displaystyle \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{\ell} = N$$

have more than four solutions? I am most interested in the case $k = \ell = 2$.

This is related to [Singmaster's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture), which asks for solutions to

$$\displaystyle \binom{m}{k} = \binom{n}{\ell}$$

where $m,n,k,\ell$ are all variable. In the above question, we are considering fixed $k, \ell$.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A264961